# Other ways of asking “what’s in the news?”

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

“What do they write in newspapers about?“ - does this sentence sound right for a native speaker? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

> What do they write in newspapers about?

This sentence should be structured as:

> What do they write **about** in newspapers?

With that said, this would actually risk sounding too general, as though you were asking:

> What is a newspaper? What do they write about?

It's because you are using "do they", in reference to something that has already been written.

Instead you could ask:

> What's in the (news)papers today?

Or for a more general overview:

> What's been in the (news)papers recently?

I've put "news" in brackets as it's an optional thing to say. "Newspaper" is often just shortened to "paper", at least in cases where the context makes it obvious that you are talking about the newspaper.